# Block (or only allow certian) incoming IP addresses on Verizon FIOS Actiontec Router

Tags: firewall, ip, fios

I opened a few ports to the outside of my home network so I can get into a few of my machines from outside. When checking some logs, I noticed that I was getting scanned on some ports from various other countries.

I already moved my port forward to a non-standard port.

I would like to be able to block specific IP's (or even subnets) from my Verizon FIOS router. There is a little bit of documentation online, but I can't find anything specific on how to do this.

To start, I just want to block a specific IP. But if it is not to hard, I would also like to know how to possibly block a range of IPs. And with the inverse of this - is there a way to allow only certain IPs or range?

Comment: I wonder, if it is possible to blacklist IP-addresses automatically -- via an API of some sort. UPnP does not seem to support this, perhaps, something Actiontec-specific exists? For example, when I see an attempt to login as "root" via ssh, I want to *automatically* blacklist the IP-address before they succeed in attacking my network through some other vector (ssh as root is not possible here, but something else may be).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actiontec Router? In the Firewall section go to the Advanced Filtering section (Network (Home/Office) Rules) > Add, you can set filters (Rules) in there, specify the IP, the protocol and set it to "drop" packets, no real way to keep open ports from port scanners, this will be a constant battle as the IPs will constantly change.

Do not set it up to "reject" packets, this will send a reply, and will indicate that you exist on the other end. Set it to "Drop" packets.

Network Home/Office includes all the underlying networks including, Ethernet, Coax, Wireless.

It is not really a problem, since unsolicited packets will not get through the nat table or firewall anyway. Be sure the firewall is set to medium.